# How to upload and encode files into azure media service

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have my website hosted in azure. I have a wcf service, which also running in azure. Now I want to upload a file from local computer to azure media service through azure website and wcf, while uploading it will call the upload function in the WCF service. while uploading I got the error, bad gatewy(502).The asset is not creating.Error occurs in create function. So how to upload media files to azure media service from local machine. I am just supplying path as input to WCF service.(e.g) c:\sampe.mp4. can I stream files form my local machine to azure media service through WCF service through website.

azure site -> upload files from local -> send path(c:\sample.mp4) to WCF -> upload function in WCF - > error in creating asset

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing web based application which is managing Azure media services account you can upload video azure storage in  2 ways:

- Web application generates SAS locator for a asset and user directly communicate to storage api to upload file.**This is preferred way since your web service is not acting as upload proxy**. See [How to upload Stream to Azure Media Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987405/how-to-upload-stream-to-azure-media-services) and   related Stack questions having pointers how to use javascript upload to azure storage. [Upload an image file to azure blob storage from js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919968/upload-an-image-file-to-azure-blob-storage-from-js)
- Web application behaves as upload proxy between user and Azure Media services. First user uploads file to your web app server and web app server uploads it to azure storage account associated with media service account. Example of file upload in mvc3 app -[File Upload ASP.NET MVC 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0). Once you have file on a server look  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dotnet-upload-files/ how to use .net sdk to upload file to azure. You have to use server file path while calling azure media services sdk upload code. Want to highlight  that this **is not preferred way since your app became a bottleneck during upload between users and azure storage**